# How to compare a value of all contracts made within particular month to it's current value in foreing currency

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to compare value of loan contracts made in a day with coresponding currency rate (CZK/EUR) within particular month and say what value the contracts have as to current month (say June).

E.g.:

```
1.5.2017 60,000 CZK, CZK/EUR = 27.125; 
1.5.2017 180,000 CZK, CZK/EUR = 27.129; 
2.5.2017 90,000 CZK, CZK/EUR = 27.019

...
= SUM(CZK), SUM(EUR) in May, EUR in June
```

So far, I've come with:

```
;WITH orig AS (
       SELECT 
          origEUR = SUM(ApprovedLoanAmount / cr.Rate)
          ,sumCZK = SUM(ApprovedLoanAmount)
       FROM dim.Contract con
          JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON con.CreateDateID = cal.DateID
          JOIN s96.CurrencyRates cr ON cr.Date = cal.Date
       WHERE (YEAR(cal.Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(cal.Date)=5) AND (CurrencyID = 1)
)

SELECT
    diff = orig.origEUR - (sumCZK / cr.Rate) --as to the current rate at the end of June
FROM orig orig
    JOIN s96.CurrencyRates cr --???
WHERE (YEAR(Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(Date)=6) AND (DAY(Date)=30) AND (CurrencyID = 1)
```

I hope, I've made my idea clear :-)

Comment: Can you give us the table definitions and some data examples ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have constants as part of `ON` conditions

```
;WITH orig AS (
       SELECT 
          origEUR = SUM(ApprovedLoanAmount / cr.Rate)
          ,sumCZK = SUM(ApprovedLoanAmount)
       FROM dim.Contract con
          JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON con.CreateDateID = cal.DateID
          JOIN s96.CurrencyRates cr ON cr.Date = cal.Date
       WHERE (YEAR(cal.Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(cal.Date)=5) AND (CurrencyID = 1)
)

SELECT
    diff = orig.origEUR - (sumCZK / cr.Rate) --as to the current rate at the end of June
FROM orig orig
    JOIN s96.CurrencyRates cr ON cr.Date = CONVERT( DATETIME, '[Pick a date]' ) -- e.g. CONVERT( DATETIME, '2017-07-01' )
WHERE (YEAR(Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(Date)=6) AND (DAY(Date)=30) AND (CurrencyID = 1)
```